# Retrieving a property of a JSON object without index?

Tags: jquery, json

I understand how to retrieve using an index (of 0 or 1) with code below, but how can I use ("name": "State Bank1") in replace of it's index value since my index value will not always be the same as my json file changes. The name value "State Bank1", "State Bank2" will always be the same.

```
var jsonData = [{
    "name": "State Bank1",
    "Currency Code": "4000",
    "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
    "Payment Channel": "check"},{
    "name": "State Bank2",
    "Currency Code": "4000",
    "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
    "Payment Channel": "check",}]

//$(":eq(index)")

$("#BankAccountName").val(jsonData**[0]**['name']);
$("#CurrencyCode").val(jsonData[0]['Currency Code']);
$("#DepositDate").val(jsonData[0]['Deposit Date']);
$("#PaymentChannel").val(jsonData[0]['Payment Channel'])
```

Here is a live code to provide what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/sb138aLc/

Comment: Loop through the array, looking for the name that you want.